# How to install the GPU

Tags: 14.04, drivers, cpu, gpu

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.04` , 
my `VGA compatible controller` :

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

and  :

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

what is my cart GPU ? and how to install GPU ?